# No muestra los datos que guardo usando python en postgreSQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

imports necesarios

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import messagebox as mb
    from tkinter import scrolledtext as st
    import  psycopg2
```

en esta función hago la conexión a la base de datos

```
    def abrir():
    conexion = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",password="1425368dd",
    dbname="postgres",port="5432",host="localh ost")

    return conexion
```

Esta es la clase que he creado, la cual contiene las partes visuales y logicas

```
    class Formulario:

         def __init__(self):
             self.ventana1=tk.Tk()


             self.ventana1.title("THE BEST MOMENT")
             self.ventana1.geometry("700x425")
             self.cuaderno1 = ttk.Notebook(self.ventana1)
             self.cuaderno1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

             self.carga_de_celulares()
             self.carga_de_cargadores()
             self.consulta_por_modelo()

             self.ventana1.mainloop()
```

Este es el frame 1

```
    def carga_de_celulares(self):
        self.pagina1 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
        self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina1, text="Carga de celulares")

        self.labelframe1=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina1, text="Artículo")
        self.labelframe1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=10)

        # SO
        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Sistema Operativo:")
        self.label1.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.entrySistema = tk.StringVar()
        self.SO = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entrySistema)
        self.SO.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

        # Marca
        self.label2 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Marca:")
        self.label2.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.entryMarca = tk.StringVar()
        self.marca = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryMarca)
        self.marca.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)

        # Modelo
        self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Modelo:")
        self.label3.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.entryModelo = tk.StringVar()
        self.modelo = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryModelo)
        self.modelo.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)

        # Almacenamiento
        self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Almacenamiento:")
        self.label3.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.entryAlmacenamiento = tk.StringVar()
        self.almacenamientottk.Entry(self.labelframe1,textvariable=self.entryAlmacenamiento)
        self.almacenamiento.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=4, pady=4)

        # memoria Ram
        self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Memoria RAM:")
        self.label3.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.entryRam = tk.StringVar()
        self.ram = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryRam)
        self.ram.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=4, pady=4)

        # Batería
        self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Cap. Batería:")
        self.label3.grid(column=0, row=6, padx=4, pady=4)

       self.entryBateria = tk.StringVar()
       self.bateria = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryBateria)
       self.bateria.grid(column=1, row=6, padx=4, pady=4)

       # pantalla
       self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Pantalla:")
       self.label3.grid(column=0, row=7, padx=4, pady=4)

       self.entryPantalla = tk.StringVar()
       self.pantalla = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryPantalla)
       self.pantalla.grid(column=1, row=7, padx=4, pady=4)

       # procesador
       self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Procesador:")
       self.label3.grid(column=0, row=8, padx=4, pady=4)

       self.entryProcesador = tk.StringVar()
       self.procesador = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryProcesador)
       self.procesador.grid(column=1, row=8, padx=4, pady=4)


       # Precio
       self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Precio:")
       self.label3.grid(column=0, row=10, padx=4, pady=4)

      self.entryPrecio = tk.StringVar()
      self.precio = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryPrecio)
      self.precio.grid(column=1, row=10, padx=4, pady=4)


      self.boton1=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="Ingresar IOS", command=self.agregarIOS)
      self.boton1.grid(column=0, row=11, padx=4, pady=4)

      self.boton2=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="Ingresar Android")
      self.boton2.grid(column=0, row=12, padx=4, pady=4)

      self.boton3=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1,text="Listadocompleto",
      command=self.listaCompletaCelulares)                                           
      self.boton3.grid(column=1,row=11, padx=4,pady=4)
```

En esto quiero hacer una lista que me muestre los datos que he guardado en postgreSQL ¿Me podrian decir como hacer eso?

```
    def listaCompletaCelulares(self):
        lista = tk.Toplevel()
        lista.title("Listado completo")



        boton = ttk.Button(lista, text="Listado completo", command=self.listar)
        boton.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
```

En esta función recupero los datos ingresados en la interfaz de "carga de celulares" para guardarlos en la base de datos de PostgreSQL

```
def agregarIOS(self):


    datos=(self.SO.get(),self.marca.get(),
           self.modelo.get(),self.almacenamiento.get(),
           self.ram.get(),self.bateria.get(),
           self.pantalla.get(),self.procesador.get(),
           self.precio.get()) 

                                                                                                                                           if datos!=0:
        cone = abrir()
        cursor = cone.cursor()

        sql = '''INSERT INTO ios("Sistema","Marca","Modelo","Almacenamiento","Ram","Bateria","Pantalla","Procesador","Precio") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''
        cursor.execute(sql, datos)

        self.entrySistema.set("")
        self.entryMarca.set("")
        self.entryModelo.set("")
        self.entryAlmacenamiento.set("")
        self.entryRam.set("")
        self.entryBateria.set("")
        self.entryPantalla.set("")
        self.entryProcesador.set("")
        self.entryPrecio.set("")
        mb.showinfo(" Información ", " Los datos fueron cargados ")

    else:
        mb.showinfo("Advertencia","No debe dejar espacios en blanco")
```

en esta funcíon hago lo mismo solo que se guardarán en la tabla "android"

```
def agregarAndroid(self):

    datos=(self.SO.get(), self.marca.get(),self.modelo.get(), self.almacenamiento.get(),self.ram.get(),
           self.bateria.get(),self.pantalla.get(), self.procesador.get(),self.precio.get(),)


    if len(datos)!=0:

        cone = abrir()
        cursor = cone.cursor()

        sql = '''INSERT INTO android("Sistema","Marca","Modelo","Almacenamiento","Ram","Bateria","Pantalla","Procesador","Precio") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''
        cursor.execute(sql, datos)

        self.entrySistema.set("")
        self.entryMarca.set("")
        self.entryModelo.set("")
        self.entryAlmacenamiento.set("")
        self.entryRam.set("")
        self.entryBateria.set("")
        self.entryPantalla.set("")
        self.entryProcesador.set("")
        self.entryPrecio.set("")
        mb.showinfo(" Información ", " Los datos fueron cargados ")

    else:
        mb.showinfo("Advertencia", "No debe dejar espacios en blanco")
```

Frame 2

```
def carga_de_cargadores(self):
    self.pagina2 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
    self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina2, text="Carga de cargadores")

    self.labelframe1=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina2, text="Artículos")
    self.labelframe1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=10)

    # Marca
    self.label2 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Marca:")
    self.label2.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)
    self.entryMarcaC = tk.StringVar()
    self.marcaC = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryMarcaC)
    self.marcaC.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)
    # Precio
    self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Precio:")
    self.label3.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)
    self.entryPrecioC = tk.StringVar()
    self.precioC = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryPrecioC)
    self.precioC.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)
    # color
    self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Color:")
    self.label3.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=4, pady=4)

    self.entryColorC = tk.StringVar()
    self.colorC = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryColorC)
    self.colorC.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=4, pady=4)
    # SO
    self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Sistema Operativo:")
    self.label1.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=4, pady=4)
    self.entrySistemaC = tk.StringVar()
    self.SOC = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entrySistemaC)
    self.SOC.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=4, pady=4)
    # Modelo
    self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Modelo:")
    self.label3.grid(column=0, row=6, padx=4, pady=4)
    self.entryModeloC = tk.StringVar()
    self.modeloC = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryModeloC)
    self.modeloC.grid(column=1, row=6, padx=4, pady=4)
    #botones
    self.boton1=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="Ingresar cargadores", command=self.agregaCargadores)
    self.boton1.grid(column=0, row=7, padx=4, pady=4)

    self.boton2=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="Listado cargadores", command = self.listaCompletaCargadores)
    self.boton2.grid(column= 1,row=7, padx=4, pady=4)
```

Esto pueden ignorarlo ya que hable de lo que quiero hacer anteriormente, no lo omito por el orden

```
def listaCompletaCargadores(self):
    lista = tk.Toplevel()
    lista.title("Listado completo")




    boton = ttk.Button(lista, text="Listado completo", command=self.listar)
    boton.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
```

En esta función igualmente busco que se guarden los datos ingresados pero no lo hace

```
def agregaCargadores(self):
    datos = (self.SO.get(), self.marca.get(), self.modelo.get(),self.colorC.get(), self.precio.get())

    if len(datos) != 0:

        cone = abrir()
        cursor = cone.cursor()

        sql = '''INSERT INTO cargadores("Sistema","Marca","Modelo","Color","Precio") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''
        cursor.execute(sql, datos)

        self.entrySistema.set("")
        self.entryMarca.set("")
        self.entryModelo.set("")
        self.entryAlmacenamiento.set("")
        self.entryRam.set("")
        self.entryBateria.set("")
        self.entryPantalla.set("")
        self.entryProcesador.set("")
        self.entryPrecio.set("")
        mb.showinfo(" Información ", " Los datos fueron cargados ")

    else:
        mb.showinfo("Advertencia", "No debe dejar espacios en blanco")
```

Frame 3

```
def consulta_por_modelo(self):

    self.pagina3 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
    self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina3, text="Consulta por modelo")

    self.labelframe1=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina3, text="Artículo")
    self.labelframe1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=10)

    #marca
    self.label1=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Modelo:")
    self.label1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)

    self.entryModelo=tk.StringVar()
    self.marca=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryModelo)
    self.marca.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)

    # SO
    self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Sistema Operativo:")
    self.label1.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

    self.entrySistema = tk.StringVar()
    self.SO = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entrySistema, state="readonly")
    self.SO.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)

    # Marca
    self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Marca:")
    self.label3.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)

    self.entryMarca = tk.StringVar()
    self.modelo = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryMarca,state="readonly")
    self.modelo.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)

    # Almacenamiento
    self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Almacenamiento:")
    self.label3.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)

    self.entryAlmacenamiento= tk.StringVar()
    self.almacenamiento = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryAlmacenamiento,state="readonly")
    self.almacenamiento.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)

    # memoria Ram
    self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Memoria RAM:")
    self.label3.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=4, pady=4)

    self.entryRam = tk.StringVar()
    self.ram = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryRam,state="readonly")
    self.ram.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=4, pady=4)

    # Batería
    self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Cap. Batería:")
    self.label3.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=4, pady=4)

    self.entryBateria = tk.StringVar()
    self.bateria = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryBateria,state="readonly")
    self.bateria.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=4, pady=4)

    # pantalla
    self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Pantalla:")
    self.label3.grid(column=0, row=6, padx=4, pady=4)

    self.entryPantalla = tk.StringVar()
    self.pantalla = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryPantalla, state="readonly")
    self.pantalla.grid(column=1, row=6, padx=4, pady=4)

    # procesador
    self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Procesador:")
    self.label3.grid(column=0, row=7, padx=4, pady=4)

    self.entryProcesador = tk.StringVar()
    self.procesador = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryProcesador, state="readonly")
    self.procesador.grid(column=1, row=7, padx=4, pady=4)


    # Precio
    self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Precio:")
    self.label3.grid(column=0, row=8, padx=4, pady=4)

    self.entryPrecio = tk.StringVar()
    self.precioC = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.entryPrecio, state="readonly")
    self.precioC.grid(column=1, row=8, padx=4, pady=4)


    self.boton1=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="Consultar", command=self.consultar)
    self.boton1.grid(column=1, row=11, padx=4, pady=4)
```

de esto pueden ignorarlo ya que estaba usando un módulo que eliminé ***texto en negrita***

```
def consultar(self):

    datos = (self.modelo.get(),)
    res = self.entrada.alta(datos)


    if len(res)>0:
        self.entrySistema.set(res[0][0])
        self.entryModelo.set(res[0][1])
        self.entryAlmacenamiento.set(res[0][2])
        self.entryRam.set(res[0][3])
        self.entryBateria.set(res[0][4])
        self.entryPantalla.set(res[0][5])
        self.entryProcesador.set(res[0][6])
        self.entryPrecio.set(res[0][7])

        mb.showinfo("Información", "Los datos fueron listados")

    else:
        mb.showinfo("Información", "No existe un artículo con dicho código")

def listado_completo(self):
    self.pagina4 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
    self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina4, text="Listado completo")
    self.labelframe1=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina4, text="Artículo")
    self.labelframe1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=10)



    self.boton1=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="Listado completo", command=self.listar)
    self.boton1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)


    self.scrolledtext1=st.ScrolledText(self.labelframe1, width=30, height=10)
    self.scrolledtext1.grid(column=0,row=1, padx=10, pady=10)

def listar(self):


    respuesta=self.articulo1.recuperar_todos()
    self.scrolledtext1.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    for fila in respuesta:
        self.scrolledtext1.insert(tk.END, "Sistema:"+str(fila[0])+
                                  "\nModelo:"+fila[1]+
                                  "\nAlmacenamiento:"+str(fila[2])+
                                  "\nMemoria Ram:"+str(fila[3])+
                                  "\nCap. bateria:"+str(fila[4])+
                                  "\nPantalla:"+str(fila[5])+
                                  "\nProcesador:"+str(fila[6])+
                                  "\nprecio"+str(fila[7])+
                                  "\n\n")


    constructor=Formulario()
```

En fin cuando yo "guardo los datos en la base de datos" me aparece la confirmación que ya estan bien guardados pero me daba un error que decia que un campo el cual tenia llave primaria ya estaba cupado lo cual no era así, entonces le quite esa llave primaria y cuando le daba a guardar solo me añadia filas con comias simplesdentro de la tabla. Y de repente ya no hace nada el programa osea ya no añade ni las filas. No entiendo por que sucede eso, espero me puedan ayudar, soy nuevo en esto de programación en python.(Estoy usando Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de escribir la pregunta con tu código. Una pregunta: cómo está definida la tabla, con qué datos intentas hacer el insert y cuál es el error específico? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade esta información

Comment: Muchas gracias, ese error ya lo resolví

Comment: Si lo resolviste, estaría muy bien que pongas abajo tu respuesta e incluso puedes aceptarla un tiempo después, para que otros sepan qué hacer si tienen el mismo lío